# I need to change a url in hundreds of wordpress articles. help?

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, .htaccess

I have a wordpress site that I moved from domain.info to domain.com. Some of the older articles still reference images at domain.info. How can I script it to replace all instances of example.info with example.com? Can I do it in MySQL without having SSH access to find and replace?

http://www.example.info/wp-content/uploads/2009/09/image-239.jpg

should be

http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/09/image-239.jpg

EDIT:

Or maybe even using .htaccess?

Comment: Edited to point to `example.com` because the old link points to a commercial site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
UPDATE mytable SET url = REPLACE(url, 'www.example.info', 'www.example.com') 
WHERE url LIKE 'http://www.example.info%'
```

or somewhat slower:

```
UPDATE mytable SET url = REPLACE(url, 'www.example.info', 'www.example.com') 
WHERE url LIKE '%www.example.info%'
```

**See:**
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_replace

Answer (score 0):

I would think that using a 301 (redirect) would be better, so you don't have SEO issues and lose any synergy you may already have.